# Understanding the formula for the height of a k-ary tree

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

So I've discovered that the formula for finding the height of a [*k*-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) is

> ceil(log_k(k-1) + log_k(n) - 1)

Where *n* is the amount of nodes or elements in the tree.

My issue is understanding this formula. How do you discover this and how is it proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is easier to think about how many nodes a k-ary tree of depth d has first and then solve the equation. So this is easy to define recursively. A tree of depth 0 has just one node. A tree of depth d + 1 has k times the size of the subtrees plus one new node, so we get

```
s(0) = 1
s(d+1) = k*s(d)+1
```

Now, there is either theory to solve such recursive equations, or you can just try to guess it and prove your guess. As that is easier, that's what we are going to do. Our assumption is:

```
s(d) = (k^(d+1)-1)/(k-1)
```

We can easily proof this by induction over the depth. The base case:

```
s(0) = 1
(k^1-1)/(k-1)=1
```

The induction step:

```
s(d+1) = k*s(d)+1 (now we apply the induction hypothesis)
= k*(k^(d+1)-1)/(k-1) + 1 = (k^((d+1)-k)+k-1)/(k-1)
= (k^((d+1)+1) - 1)/(k-1)
```

So now we've proven that we just solve that equation:

```
s = (k^(d+1)-1)/(k-1)
s*(k-1)+1 = k^(d+1)
log_k(s*(k-1)+1) = d+1
d = log_k(s*(k-1)+1)-1
```

Almost there. Now we are only interested in natural numbers and we know that log_k(s*(k-1)+1) always has to be a natural number if s and k are. We also know that log_k(x+1) - log_k(x) < 1 for any k >= 2 and x > 1. So we can write this as:

```
d = ceil(log_k(s*(k-1))-1)
= ceil(log_k(s)+log_k(k-1))-1)
```